# Checkbox in List View ABAP

Tags: checkbox, abap

[image: Example]

I want to do a simple thing but I don't have any idea. I made a button in GUI status it has a functon key and it works. Now the real thing. I want that for every checkbox I mark, when I press the button to call a new screen to show me only the entries that were checked.

The checkbox is added in the itable, but I think it doesn't matter that much. How can I tell the button which checkboxes on screen where checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty much what Bernard said, though it is lacking some detail.

You will need to know how many lines you wrote, this is stored in SY-LINNO, note that you need to also take into account how many pages you outputted which is stored in SY-PAGNO and how many lines are on a page which is stored in SY-LINCT.

You could get that info, which is probably a better approach, with 'DESCRIBE LIST'.

Then for each line with the command 'READ LINE' you can find the value of the checkbox.

```
READ LINE line OF PAGE page [result].
```

From there things should be a piece of cake.

Comment: Thx a lot guys. I used the READ LINE statement. I had to show a popup with POPUP DISPLAY. The Loop couldn't help me, because i had to read the lines, not show them. And yes this is just an exercise :) Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For the checked records the checkbox field is 'X', while for the unchecked records the checkbox field is space (' '). So you need to loop over the records on the screen, then only display the ones where the checkbox is equal 'X'.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the answers you already got, you don't want to dig into interactive list programming any deeper (unless you have to do this for a programming exercise). Take a look at the [ALV Object Model Documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/5e/88d440e14f8431e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm) and the SALV_DEMO_* example programs.